# Adobe reader shows error on mac when trying to open pdf which is created using iText library

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have created PDF using `iText` library with dynamic document size .
Document size is depends on content. 
It is opening fine in `windows` but when trying to open in `MAC` its show error **"message error exist on this . page acrobat may not display the page correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document."**

I have added image in header using absolute position.
When I remove this image then it working fine.
I have check every pixel there is no any pixel is overlapping each others. 
I don't know exactly what wrong in this code.

Find my code below

```
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    cb.saveState();
    try {
        //Header and Footer Setting
        float textBase = document.bottom();
        float textTop = document.top();
        String ramboAccounturl = docRoot + RamboConstants.DEFAULT_LOGO_IMAGE_PATH;
        Image ramboImage = Image.getInstance(ramboAccounturl);
        String reviewName = displayName;//"Review: " + review.getReviewName();

        //Header Horizontal Line
        cb.setLineWidth(1);
        cb.closePath();
        //Footer Horizontal Line
        float footerY = document.bottom();
        footerY += 10;
        cb.setColorStroke(BaseColor.BLACK);;
        cb.moveTo(document.left(), footerY);
        cb.lineTo(document.right(), footerY);
        cb.stroke();
        cb.setColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
        Image bkgImage = Image.getInstance(docRoot + RamboConstants.BACKGROUNG_IMAGE);
        cb.addImage(bkgImage, document.right() - document.rightMargin() + 35f, 0, 0, RamboConstants.PDF_LOGO_MAX_HEIGHT + 8f,
                document.left() - 20, textTop - 18f);
        cb.beginText();
        //account logo image
        account.setDirectS3Download(RamboConstants.TRUE);
        Image image = null;
        String accountLogoUrl = ramboContext.getFileManager().buildFileUrl(account, RamboConstants.DOCTYPE_LOGO_HEADER_ACCOUNT, null);
        if (accountLogoUrl != null) {
            try {
                image = Image.getInstance(new URL(accountLogoUrl));
            } catch(Exception e) {
                ramboAccounturl = docRoot + RamboConstants.DEFAULT_LOGO_WHITE_IMAGE_PATH;
                image = Image.getInstance(ramboAccounturl);
            }
        } else {
            ramboAccounturl = docRoot + RamboConstants.DEFAULT_LOGO_WHITE_IMAGE_PATH;
            image = Image.getInstance(ramboAccounturl);
        }
        image.setAbsolutePosition(document.left() - 4f, textTop - 12f);
        float width = image.getWidth() * RamboConstants.PDF_REVIEW_PIXEL_TO_USER_POINT_CONVERSION_RATE;
        float height = image.getHeight() * RamboConstants.PDF_REVIEW_PIXEL_TO_USER_POINT_CONVERSION_RATE;
        if (width > RamboConstants.PDF_LOGO_MAX_WIDTH){ // source is wider than target in proportion
            float ratio = RamboConstants.PDF_LOGO_MAX_WIDTH / width;
            width = width * ratio;
            height = height * ratio;      
        }
        if (height > RamboConstants.PDF_LOGO_MAX_HEIGHT){ 
            float ratio = RamboConstants.PDF_LOGO_MAX_HEIGHT / height;
            width = width * ratio;
            height = height * ratio;      
        } 
        image.scaleAbsoluteWidth(width);
        image.scaleAbsoluteHeight(height);
        cb.addImage(image);

        //review name
        cb.setColorFill(BaseColor.WHITE);
        cb.setFontAndSize(helv , RamboConstants.PDF_REVIEW_NAME_FONT_SIZE);
        cb.setTextMatrix(document.right() - helv.getWidthPoint(reviewName, RamboConstants.PDF_REVIEW_NAME_FONT_SIZE) - 
                40, textTop + 5);
        cb.showText(reviewName);

        cb.setColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
        //rambo account logo
        ramboImage.setAbsolutePosition(document.left(), textBase - 25);
        width = ramboImage.getWidth();
        height = ramboImage.getHeight();
        if (width > RamboConstants.PDF_ROBOHEAD_LOGO_MAX_WIDTH){ // source is wider than target in proportion
            float ratio = RamboConstants.PDF_ROBOHEAD_LOGO_MAX_WIDTH / width;
            width = width * ratio;
            height = height * ratio;
        }
        if (height > RamboConstants.PDF_ROBOHEAD_LOGO_MAX_HEIGHT){ 
            float ratio = RamboConstants.PDF_ROBOHEAD_LOGO_MAX_HEIGHT / height;
            width = width * ratio;
            height = height * ratio;      
        } 
        ramboImage.scaleAbsoluteWidth(width);
        ramboImage.scaleAbsoluteHeight(height);
        cb.addImage(ramboImage);
        //powered by text
        String poweredByText = ramboContext.getMessageSource().getMessage("msg_footer_powered_by", null, Locale.getDefault());
        cb.setFontAndSize(BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 
                10);
        cb.setTextMatrix(document.left() + 70, 20);
        cb.showText(poweredByText);

        //Page number
        String text = "Page " + writer.getPageNumber() + " of ";
        cb.setFontAndSize(helv , RamboConstants.PDF_FOOTER_FONT_SIZE);
        cb.setTextMatrix(document.right() - helv.getWidthPoint(text, RamboConstants.PDF_FOOTER_FONT_SIZE) - 
                RamboConstants.PDF_FOOTER_FONT_SIZE, 20);
        cb.showText(text);
        cb.endText();
        cb.addTemplate(total, document.right() - RamboConstants.PDF_FOOTER_FONT_SIZE, 20);  

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to add header footer to PDF page ");
    }

    cb.restoreState();
```

[image]

My pdf looks like this. I have added above code in `onEndPage()` event this code is for generate header and footer part.

[image]

Comment: Billions of PDFs have been created using iText and most of them open correctly on every possible PDF viewer. Maybe you aren't creating your PDFs correctly, but as you don't show any code, nor the PDF that causes the problem, you should not expect an answer. When posting a question on StackOverflow, saying "it doesn't work" is not sufficient. You have to explain what you've tried, show the result and provide sufficient info if you want people to help you.

Comment: Thank u Bruno for quick response , but the same PDF is opening correctly in windows please give me any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding content using `PdfContentByte` which means that you consider yourself as proficient in PDF. However, I see that you have the following line:

```
cb.beginText();
```

This opens a text object. Inside a text object, there are some strict rules that you need to follow. For instance: the first thing you add to the direct content after beginning a text object is an image. That's not correct, is it?

Also, you cannot have a `beginText()` without an `endText()`.

This is the most blatant error in your code. You may have other errors. While some PDF viewers may be tolerant towards people who violate the PDF specification, others are more strict.

Comment: Yes , i have added endtext() method at end of this method but i have not added whole code  just added code where the error is coming. when i remove this image its working on MAC also.

Comment: Please see code again which is generating header and footer for PDF. Please let me know if any solution.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you create a text object when in reality you want to add an image. I have looked at your updated code and it looks like something that will be very hard to maintain. You should simplify it.

Comment: I am adding some text in header and footer part that's why begin text is added.

Comment: For instance: you start with `closePath()`, but there isn't any path to close. It's as if you just threw in a bunch of lines of code without knowing what you're doing. Also: you do not listen to what I'm saying. You are adding an image inside a text block! Don't do that!

Comment: Thank u Bruno Lowagie for your response , i have comment this close path but still showing error on mac . It looks like adobe  readers issue on mac machine.

Comment: My requirement is  add background image in header on that image add logo on left corner and text on right corner of header part for that using absolute position .  Please see new added PDF.

Comment: Thank you !! Bruno , this issue is fixed thank you for your help . this is due to i am adding image within begin text and end text. this is not valid on MAC.

Comment: That is *exactly* what I told you in my original answer: *the first thing you add to the direct content after beginning a text object is an image. That's not correct, is it?* ;-) You may want to accept the answer.